# NameError: name 'tweets_source' not defined | But it has default value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code:

```
import json

class TweetFormatter():

    def __init__(self, source_file='twitter_data.txt'):
        self.tweets_source = source_file

    def convert2json(self, tweets_source=None):
        tweets_data = []
        if tweets_source is None:
            if self.tweets_source is not None:
                tweets_source = self.tweets_source
            else:
                raise ValueError("You need to specify a file")

        with open(tweets_source, "r") as tweets_file:
            for line in tweets_file:
                try:
                    tweet = json.loads(line)
                    tweets_data.append(tweet)
                except:
                    continue
        return tweets_data
```

And I'm calling convert2json method like:

```
formatter = TweetFormatter('twitter_data.txt')
tweets = formatter.convert2json()
```

Python throws error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "analysis.py", line 12, in <module>
    tweets = formatter.convert2json()
File "/home/azaroma/analisis-machismo/app/tweet_formatter.py", line 11, in convert2json
with open(tweets_source, "r") as tweets_file: 
NameError: name 'tweets_source' is not defined
```

I believe that `tweets_source` should be defined because it has a default value. Also, if a i call `formatter.convert2json('twitter_data.txt')` python throws:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "analysis.py", line 12, in <module>
tweets = formatter.convert2json('twitter_data.txt')
TypeError: convert2json() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

This has to be something really simple but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Can't recreate this, `tweets_data` will be undefined, not `tweets_source`.

Comment: Does the indentation in your example code match that of your actual code? What do you expect `tweets = formatter.convert2json()` to do? It looks to me like it will return `None`.

Comment: @elethan I expect that if the caller does not provide a source file, the program looks if the caller has provided one when she constructed the TwitterMiner object; if there isn't any of the two files, an exception rises. Else, if there is a file to get the data from, the program return the data in a list

Comment: But you only read from `tweets_source` - `with open(tweets_source, "r") as tweets_file` - if `tweet_source`  is not `None` when initially called, i.e., if you do `formatter.convert2json()`, the outermost `else` will never be reached. This, combined with the errors you are seeing, makes me think that the indentation in your example code, does not match the code you are executing.

Comment: @elethan I get it: even when I assign a filename value, the else clause will not be executed. The solution is to remove the else clause.

Comment: Yes. Once you removed the `else`, does your code work, or do you still have the same error?

Comment: @elethan It has the same error, I fear. Indentation matches the one of the code posted. Are you able to reproduce it?

Comment: You should update the traceback if you are going to update the code

Comment: @MarioGil No, I am not able to reproduce, and can't see how you could possibly get those errors. If `tweets_source` is not defined, then it should fail on the first `if` and never reach the `with`. Make sure you don't have any outdated `.pyc` files lying around that are being read instead of your current code.

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm sorry but it's the same traceback. The program fails in the same line.

Comment: Try removing the `.pyc` files or the `__pycache__` directory. The line `with open(tweets_source, "r") as tweets_file:` does not seem to appear on line 11 as the traceback suggests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @elethan and @cricket_007 that confirmed the error could not be reproduced because I found out that my emacs' theme does not show the 'file does not exist' character. I was working on another file. In some point I copied the file and didn't kill the emacs buffer, that's why changes weren't reflecting in execution. Sorry.